# Spring Security unexpected behavior for REST endpoints authentication?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The scenario we are looking for is as follows:

1. client connects with REST to a REST login url
2. Spring microservice (using Spring Security) should return `200 OK` and a login token
3. the client keeps the token
4. the client calls other REST endpoints using the same token.

However, I see that the client is getting `302` and a `Location` header, together with the token. So it does authenticate, but with un-desired HTTP response status code and header.

The Spring Security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()  // Refactor login form
               // See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11496
            .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
...
}
```

I tried adding interceptors and filters but can't see where 302 and Location being set and added in Spring side.
However, the `Location` header does show in the response headers received at the client side (together with the rest of the Spring Security headers [LINK](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html)):

```
Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma=no-cache
Expires=0
X-Frame-Options=DENY, SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=D1C1F1CE1FF4E1B3DDF6FA302D48A905; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location=http://ec2-35-166-130-246.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8108/ <---- ouch
Content-Length=0
Date=Thu, 22 Dec 2016 20:15:20 GMT
```

Any suggestion how to make it work as expected ("200 OK", no Location header and the token)?

NOTE: using Spring Boot, Spring Security, no UI, just client code calling REST endpoints.

Comment: what we're trying to do is to have a url when the app logs in with POST and credentials, and receives a the login token. not clear to me why there should be a 302. I may be missing something...

Comment: //client calls:

new RestTemplate().execute(SIGIN_URL, HttpMethod.POST, 
 new RequestCallback() { ...},
 new ResponseExtractor... {
   public Object extractData(... ){
//status code is 302 now
     headersToUpdate.add("Cookie", response.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie"));
     return null;
}

(No UI and buttons)

Comment: it is redirecting to a new url

Answer (score 2):

If you need a rest api, you must not use `http.formLogin()`. It generates form based login as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity).

Instead you can have this configuration

```
httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .disable()
                .addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Create a class, `AuthTokenFilter` which extends Spring `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and override `doFilter` method, which checks for an authentication token in every request and sets `SecurityContextHolder` accordingly.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, " + tokenHeader);

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(tokenHeader);
        String username = this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken); // Create some token utility class to manage tokens

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(-------------);
            // Create an authnetication as above and set SecurityContextHolder
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Then create an `AuthenticationController`, mapped with `/login` url, which checks credentials, and returns token.

```
/*
* Perform the authentication. This will call Spring UserDetailsService's loadUserByUsername implicitly
* BadCredentialsException is thrown if username and password mismatch
*/
Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
     new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
            authenticationRequest.getPassword()
     )
);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);        
UserDetailsImp userDetails = (UserDetailsImp) authentication.getPrincipal();
// Generate token using some Token Utils class methods, using this principal
```

To understand `loadUserByUsername` , `UserDetailsService` and `UserDetails`, please refer [Spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-components)
    }

For better understanding, please thoroughly read above link and subsequent chapters.

Comment: @Ramanujan, I have a first working baseline. I'll read the links you sent, review the code and update. thanks!

Comment: still struggling with the long and not-so-clear documentation. Meanwhile, could you please also add advice on how to handle the logout (e.g., invalidation of the authToken, not using redirect etc..)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a 302 response telling the browser to redirect to your login page. What do you expect to happen? 302 response must have a Location header.

Comment: the client connects to /signin which is the login url. so I'm actually expecting to see 200. 
am I missing something?
can you share more info?

Comment: perhaps I'll repharese - what should I change in order to get 200 status code and no Location header?

Comment: @Roy you cannot. Is the `/signin` url meant for browsers or is this a login endpoint for API clients to get some sort of token? If it is to get a token, then how is this token meant to be used after the client obtains it?

Answer (score 1):

`http.formLogin()`

is designed for form-based login. So the 302 status and Location header in the response is expected if you attempt to access a protected resource without being authenticated.

Based on your requirement/scenario,

> 1. client connects with REST to a REST login url

have you considered using HTTP Basic for authentication?

`http.httpBasic()`

Using HTTP Basic, you can populate the Authorization header with the username/password and the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` will take care of authenticating the credentials and populating the SecurityContext accordingly.

I have a [working example](https://github.com/jgrandja/messaging-sample) of this using Angular on the client-side and Spring Boot-Spring Security on back-end.

If you look at `security-service.js`, you will see a factory named `securityService` which provides a `login()` function. This function calls the `/principal` endpoint with the `Authorization` header populated with the username/password as per HTTP Basic format, for example:

`Authorization : Basic base64Encoded(username:passsword)`

The `BasicAuthenticationFilter` will process this request by extracting the credentials and ultimately authenticating the user and populating the `SecurityContext` with the authenticated principal. After authentication is successful, the request will proceed to the destined endpoint `/principal` which is mapped to `SecurityController.currentPrincipal` which simply returns a json representation of the authenticated principal.

For your remaining requirements:

> 2. Spring microservice (using Spring Security) should return 200 OK and a login token
> 3. the client keeps the token
> 4. the client calls other REST endpoints using the same token.

You can generate a security/login token and return that instead of the user info. However, I would highly recommend looking at [Spring Security OAuth](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) if you have a number of REST endpoints deployed across different Microservices that need to be protected via a security token. Building out your own STS (Security Token Service) can become very involved and complicated so not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler and override method "onAuthenticationSuccess" to change the response status as per your need.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> tokenMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tokenMap.put("token", accessToken.getToken());
    tokenMap.put("refreshToken", refreshToken.getToken());
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), tokenMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default logout success handler to avoid redirect. In spring boot2 you can do as below:

```
....logout().logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse,authentication)->{
                //do nothing not to redirect
        })
```

For more details: Please check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/521847/Logout-Spring-s-LogoutFilter).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `headers().defaultsDisabled()` and then chain that method to add the specific headers you want.